# Visual Basic with MS Access 2003 date to string need ideas

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a database and from that i am pulling a date value but in my software i need to convert it to a string value so i can put it into textboxes etc. 
for the name and surname i have this line of code:

```
CustomerDataGridView.DataSource = 
    Me.CFSDataSet.Customer.Select(("name LIKE'" & nmtxt.Text & "%' AND surname LIKE'" & sntxt.Text & "%'"))
```

i need to do this for the dob but since its not a string and cannot be bothered like any other data types, my only idea is the conversion but i couldnt be able to do it.
Thanks

Comment: is this vba or vb.net? why have you tagged both?

Comment: Not for nothing but rather than rebuilding the dataset, you can use a DataView for things like that.

Comment: Did someone say little bobby tables?

Comment: `#` delimits a literal date: `WHERE datefield = #mm/dd/yyyy#`

Comment: You are vulnerable to SQL injection, type `'` into nmtxt and see what happens

Comment: its for vba i accidently tagged it. Now its untagged.
the thing is when i want to search customers by date of birth it needs to be string to be able to find relevant match cause those searches going to be including wildcards like ( starting with and including /dob%  /%dob%)

Comment: Try: `CStr(your_date)` .

Comment: solved with little bit research
("Convert(dob, 'System.String') LIKE '" & dob.Text & "%'")